# GET Django products and their thumbnails from foreignKey with single query

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I have these two Django models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=10000)

class Thumnbnail(models.Model):
    thumnbnail=models.ImageField(null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='related_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

User inputs some keyword, and based on that, I filter the product names, and matching product names are shown, together with all their product's thumbnails.

What is the most efficient way to retrieve all the products, and all their thumbnails, without querying twice separately for the products and for the thumbnails?

I know that using .select_related() we can fetch the foreign objects as well, but we can make either

a) two separate serializers for each model separately, thus requiring to have two separate viewsets, two querysets and two accesses to the database, or

b) nested Serializer, with fields from both models, but in that case we will get repeating data, the product_description will appear in every row for every thumbnail, which is also a problem, since that description can be many characters long, and will be an overkill to repeat it. Omitting it from the fields is not an option either, as I do need to get it at least once somehow.

Is there a third, more efficient way? I expect this to be possible with accessing the database only once, but I can't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: Interesting question! Usually, when I really want to minimize SQL transactions I'll create a function base view and directly call my native SQL script. This way anyone on my team that has some strong experience with SQL can always understand how it works. Anyway, I would love to know if there are other ways that can optimize SQL performance without sacrificing Django ORM.